# Database unique constraint constraint

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm having a relation problem with my database:

When I execute the code on my database manager in order to test it, it draws me an error:

> "*THERE IS NO UNIQUE CONSTRAINT MATCHING GIVEN KEYS FOR REFERENCED
> TABLE* **compras**"

https://dbdiagram.io/d/634e9b02470941019587dd03 << *Link to the database ER diagram*

Since the table accounts can have many **compras** and an **compras** can have many **tickets** they must be relationed, I'm trying to see how can I solve that constraint problem but I couldn't find the problem until now.

[image: TABLE RELATION PROBLEM]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the error, I've put the foreign key in the wrong table it was inverse than I've done, fixed!

Updated ER diagram: https://dbdiagram.io/d/634e9b02470941019587dd03